# Changing name of web service class after created

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I wrote a quick and dirty web service in VB.NET.  And as it always goes, I want to move it to production, but don't want to use the name Service1 for the public class.  When I change the name I get an error when trying to reference it.  I know there is somewhere else I need to change the class name, something in the code behind but I can't find where it is.  Does anyone have any ideas where to find this?

Allen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the designer file for the service, you may need to change it in there as well.

Comment: How do I do that in VS2008 IDE?

Comment: Right click on the .svc file and click 'View markup", you need to change "Service1" in there to the name of your class.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I knew it had to be around somewhere.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio 2008 when u add webservice ref and when you click on service1.asmx it does not show you the "<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="service1.asmx.cs" Class=".service1" %>"  instead it goes to code view.

search for 'codebehind" in your solution  and you will see service1.asmx file opened and change the Class in the above tag to Namespace.Mywebservice(or as desired)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of it, no problem.  You just need to update your reference to the service.  In my experience, sometimes it takes the IDE a little time to reflect the changes made to a local web service.

Comment: I've tried that.  When I try to add the reference I get an error and it shows me the error below.  My line 1 isn't that one, guess I could run a substring on the directory to find it.

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'FormService.Service1'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="FormService.asmx.vb" Class="FormService.Service1" %>

 

Source File: /FormService.asmx    Line: 1

Comment: Yes you need to update your reference!  Don't you see the class name in here: `Class="FormService.Service1"`?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, this is the problem (in FormService.asmx):

```
Class="FormService.Service1"
```

You need to change Service1 to your new service name.

To explain a bit, the asmx page is making a class reference to your service code, this is how the front end page and the back end code behind are wired together (even though we don't really think in terms of services having "pages") - its the same as for pages and user controls.

Comment: I did change the class name to:
Public Class JEBFormsService
Just can't find where to change Class="....."

Comment: You've got it now, in FormsService.asmx - not FormService.asmx.cs